# Ubuntu freezing during copying file to phone

Tags: mtp

Whenever I try to copy files between my phone and Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop LTS,system freezes after a while (during middle of the copying process). What might be the reason ? Is this a bug ? I can assure there's no issues with my phone since my primary OS windows 11) has rock stable connection with my phone( doesn't freeze at all) Ubuntu seems to have problem with MTP. I have been facing this issue sine long in any device(phone) I connect. If this is solvable by any means , I'm ready to take the step. By the way I was copying from Ubuntu to my phone.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you need to install the [mtp-tools](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/mtp-tools.1.html)?  `sudo apt install mtp-tools`

Comment: Do you mean, the system freezes completely? Can you switch to a VTY? You can "ungrab" the key input from the graphics [with Alt + SysRq + r](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key), and then switch to a VTY and try to see journal entries of what happened with `journalctl`. Yes, that does look like a bug.

Comment: Yeah, but that won't solve my problem. I'm not expert in using linux, just started using it for daily driving. By the way  I don't see any 'SysRq' on my keyboard.

Comment: SysRq is usually the same key as "PrintScreen". Which of questions did you answer "yeah" to? Btw, please tag a `@user` when replying, otherwise they won't be notified.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me right now in a virtual machine  with ubuntu 22.04 LTS. When I do scp to copy a regular file ~50 MB it freezes, when I copy to it large file to it is ok.

I removed the adapter type ‘vmxnet3’ and add an ‘E1000’ adapter, tested and scp 5GB file and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and mine was solved by disabling the ubuntu dock extension. I don't know how or why but the issue was gone.